# Unable to play videos in wxWidgets sample Media player?

Tags: c++, user-interface, media-player, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am using wxWidgets samples code for media player. Here first we need to select the file from the wxFileDialog and on clicking play button it will play the video.

But I don't want to select the file from the wxFileDialog, I am passing the video path in `DoOpenFile(path, bNewPage);` and then clicking on play button then the video is not playing.

```
void wxMediaPlayerFrame::OnPlay(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    DoOpenFile(_("D:\\myvideo.mp4"), false);
    wxMediaPlayerNotebookPage* currentpage = (wxMediaPlayerNotebookPage*)m_notebook->GetCurrentPage();

 ....
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: what is your wx version? What OS? Can you play the file in the sample?

Comment: I am using wxWidgets-3.1.4, windows 10 OS. And yes file is playing in the sample. I think because I am adding in filepath in `OnPlay`, it is trying to play even before the file is completely loaded. Am I right?

Comment: @badaishabaz, you do need to load the file prior to playing. Just do exactly what the sample is doing and everything will be fine...

Comment: I don't want all the controls, and menu bar. Just Play & Pause button.

Comment: my point is that you can't play the video without loading it first.